# Updating the default index number_of_replicas setting for new indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've tried updating the number of replicas as follows, according to the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html)

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_settings' -d '
{ "index" : { "number_of_replicas" : 4 } }'
```

This correctly changes the replica count for existing nodes. However, when logstash creates a new index the following day, number_of_replicas is set to the old value.

Is there a way to permanently change the default value for this setting without updating all the `elasticsearch.yml` files in the cluster and restarting the services?

FWIW I've also tried

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/logstash-*/_settings' -d '
{ "index" : { "number_of_replicas" : 4 } }'
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you can use index templates. Index templates are a great way to set default settings (including mappings) for new indices created in a cluster.

> **Index Templates**
>
> Index templates allow to define templates that will automatically be
>   applied to new indices created. The templates include both settings
>   and mappings, and a simple pattern template that controls if the
>   template will be applied to the index created.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

For your example:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_template/logstash_template' -d ' 
{ 
  "template" : "logstash-*", 
  "settings" : {"number_of_replicas" : 4 }
} '
```

This will set the default number of replicas to 4 for all new indexes that match the name "logstash-*". Note that this will not change existing indexes, only newly created ones.

Comment: (ES 5.2 at least) Except don't use a PUT for that; assumming that there was already a template there (eg. filebeat), you would have just overwrote it. Either use a POST (where supported), or first GET the entire template as a JSON document, edit it, and then PUT it.

Comment: PUT doesn't overwrite, as mentioned on the comment above. It is safe to use PUT, the docs have examples using PUT.

Comment: Is there a way I can set this in my filebeat outputs for elasticsearch too ? I dont want to create curl requests. Thanks in advance!