# How to (persistently) update the index.number_of_replicas setting in Elasticsearch without restarting the cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

In a running Elasticsearch cluster, the index.number_of_replicas setting in the configuration file is 1.

I could update this to 2 on a running cluster, by running

```
# curl -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_settings?pretty" \
   -d '{ "index": {"number_of_replicas":2}}'
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}
```

Elasticsearch immediately creates the extra replicas for existing indexes.

However, newly created indexes have only 1 replica. How can the setting be persisted for newly created indexes too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating the default index number\_of\_replicas setting for new indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553718/updating-the-default-index-number-of-replicas-setting-for-new-indices)

Answer (score 3):

The API you used is to dynamically update the replica settings for existing indices.
If you want to apply them for the indices to be created in future , a better approach would be to use  index template.
You can find more information on it [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/indices-templates.html).

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/template_1 -d '
{
    "template" : "*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 2
    }
}'
```

The above should work find for your case.

Comment: Hi is there way to specify these (or attributes) in config (elasticsearch.yml) itself..Everywhere I have only seen updating stuff via APIs?

Comment: The log says that node settings file must not have index settings, so i suppose its not possible