# How to configure logstash to create an elasticsearch index?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, logstash

elasticsearch version: elasticsearch-2.2.0.rpm
logstash version: logstash-2.2.2-1.noarch.rpm

I start elasticsearch, then logstash with /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf having a basic stdin/stdout, but no elasticsearch index is created. If I add the following to my logstash output configuration I get an index that indicates a yellow status:

action => "create"
index => "main_index"

The reason it's yellow, and not usable, is because the number of shards is 5 and replicas is 3. If I run:

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index2/' -d '
index :
   number_of_shards : 1
   number_of_replicas : 0
'

"index2" is green and usable. How do I tell either logstash and/or elasticsearch that I want my index to have 1 shard with 0 replicas without issuing a curl command?

Thanks.

Comment: Would index templates work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553718/updating-the-default-index-number-of-replicas-setting-for-new-indices

Comment: Also maybe this read would probably provide some better context to your predicament... https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/issues/324

Answer (score 4):

You have three solutions:

1. You override the [default index template](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json) that Logstash uses and you [provide your own](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template) with the proper settings, i.e. with `"number_of_replicas": 0`
2. You create an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) in ES with the proper index settings
3. In `elasticsearch.yml`, you change the setting called `index.number_of_replicas`and set it to 0 (and then restart your ES)

Comment: Solution 3 does not work on version 5.0.1 (and probably on any 5.x), as index level configurations are disabled from config files: "Since elasticsearch 5.x index level settings can NOT be set on the nodes
configuration like the elasticsearch.yaml". Source: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18073

Comment: Good point @sebaGra. That still leaves two other solutions, though ;-)

Comment: Indeed @Val, I just tried out option 1 and worked like a charm :). I'm adding an example to your answer, as I had to gather some info from here and there to get it working.

Comment: @sebaGra just create another answer referencing mine.

Answer (score 2):

In order to complete [Val´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35618591/2161698), here is an update for ES version 5.x:

Solution 3 would not work as index level configurations are disabled from config files: "Since elasticsearch 5.x index level settings can NOT be set on the nodes configuration like the elasticsearch.yaml"

Solution 1 does work, and below is an example:

- Download and edit the base template for ES 5.x from [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template-es5x.json).
- Change template name to match your index name pattern, and add the index settings you wanted to update in the first place:

  ```
  {
    "template" : "syslog*",
    "version" : 50001,
    "settings" : {
     "index.refresh_interval" : "5s",
     "index.number_of_replicas" : 0,
     "index.number_of_shards" : 1
    },
  ...
  }
  ```
- Update the logstash configuration so the output uses the created template:

  ```
  output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "syslog%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      template => "path_to_your_template.json"
      template_name => "syslog*"
      template_overwrite => true
    }
  }
  ```
- Restart the service

Answer (score 0):

For instance, You could create a small index—just one primary shard—and no replica shards with the following request:

```
   PUT /my_index
       {
        "settings": {
            "number_of_shards" :   1,
            "number_of_replicas" : 0
       }
       }
```